# How read slack channel messages using python-slackclient

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I want to get messages from my slack channel "general", may be with parameter like retrieve last 50 Messages.

I checked [documents](https://python-slackclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conversations.html), there are all stuff like sending message, listing channels, leaving channels, finding channel ID's etc. But I didn't found anything which can help me to get channel's messages "once" using that channel ID.

Is this function available in python-slackclient. Or any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) method, which pulls the last 100 message events of a conversation. The [sample code](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history/code) is pretty straightforward:

```
import os
# Import WebClient from Python SDK (github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk)
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_sdk.errors import SlackApiError

# WebClient insantiates a client that can call API methods
# When using Bolt, you can use either `app.client` or the `client` passed to listeners.
client = WebClient(token=os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"))
# Store conversation history
conversation_history = []
# ID of the channel you want to send the message to
channel_id = "C12345"

try:
    # Call the conversations.history method using the WebClient
    # conversations.history returns the first 100 messages by default
    # These results are paginated, see: https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history$pagination
    result = client.conversations_history(channel=channel_id)

    conversation_history = result["messages"]

    # Print results
    logger.info("{} messages found in {}".format(len(conversation_history), id))

except SlackApiError as e:
    logger.error("Error creating conversation: {}".format(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting Channel ID's you can use api_calls to retrieve messages like this

```
history = client.api_call(api_method='conversations.history',data={'channel':'CHANNEL_ID_HERE'})
print(history)
```